# Is an object created before assignment in python?

Tags: python, object

How many objects are created when the below mentioned program is run in python 2.7.6?
*I'm aware that an error message occurs after the execution and I'm also aware that strings are immutable and that's the reason behind the error message. What I really want to know is to find whether an object 's' is being created before the error or not?

```
string = "abcd"
string[1] = "s"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code:

```
string = "abcd"
```

An immutable `str` object will be created from `"abcd"`.  The name `string` becomes a *reference* to that object, and the reference count is incremented.  Note that there is a name in the standard library called `string`, and if you had imported it then that name will no longer refer to the module, but to `"abcd"`.

```
string[1] = "s"
```

An immutable `str` object will be created from `"s"`, but the assignment fails, so the reference count is not incremented.  In theory that means it can be garbage collected, unless something else already references `"s"`.  In practice there are optimisation features that might not destroy the object at once, those are implementation dependant and should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 3):

It is. A call `string.__setitem__(1, "s")` will be made. So, the string object has to exist to make the call. The call is BTW not guaranteed to fail. `__setitem__` can be overridden and have nearly any behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convince yourself that the object `'s'` is created beforehand (as explained in the other answers) you could use the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) (available since Python 3.8):

```py
IIn [4]: string = 'abcd'

In [5]: string[1] = (obj := 's')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-3049f7ccfa62>", line 1, in <module>
    string[1] = (obj := 's')

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment


In [6]: obj
Out[6]: 's'
```